# Source files listed in Linux executable

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, strip

Running `strings` on an ELF 64-bit LSB executable built with gcc 4.9.2 for GNU/Linux 2.6.32 on Linux Mint, I saw

- `some/path/sourcefile1.cpp`
- `some/path/sourcefile2.cpp`
- etc

I do not want the source paths and file names in the resulting executable. I tried to remove them using `strip --strip-all binaryName` but still the paths and filenames persist.

This was built with CMake. I gave CMake a `-s` flag to pass on to the compiler, but it appeared to have no effect on the outcome. I do not believe the binary was built with debug symbols. I told CMake to make a release build.

Regardless of how it was built, I expected that `strip` should be able to remove the paths and file names of the source code.

**How do I remove this information from the resulting binary?** I do not care about the size of the executable.

---

Update:

Here is what I still see with `strings`:

```
/home/kmort/longPathHere/filename1.cpp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/filename2.dir/__/__/__/__/__/longPathHere/filenam‌​e1.cpp.o 
/home/kmort/longPathHere/filename2.cpp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/filename2.dir/__/__/__/__/__/longPathHere/filenam‌​e2.cpp.o
etc
```

- There were `__FILE__` references. I have removed those.
- After I have stripped the binary, `objdump --syms` results in "no symbols".
- I am using `-DNDEBUG`. All `-g` entries have been removed, so I'm not compiling for debug.
- `readelf` only shows one thing I don't want in there, and it's the `Library rpath`, which I think I can remove no problem.
- Though I see the path and file names of the source files, there is a `.o` at the end, which makes me think it's coming from the linker.
- The `-auxbase-strip` makes me think `-fno-compare-debug` should help, but it does not.
- Prior to building, I delete the build folder and run `cmake .. --DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, which should give me a clean release build.

This is baffling to me.

Comment: perhaps there are used macros like `assert()` which include a `__FILE__`

Comment: Try removing debugging symbols with `-g0` compiler flag

Answer (score 4):

Your source code almost certainly invokes the `__FILE__` macro for
diagnostic/debugging purposes. These invocations expand to source file paths that
cannot be stripped because they are static program data.

You say you are making a Release build. You should be able
to define preprocessor macros for your release build that eliminate all
debugging code from compilation. Either you have not done so or
the conditional-compilation directives in your source code are faulty and fail to
eliminate some invocations of `__FILE__` even in a release build.

The likeliest scenario is that you have calls to the `assert()` macro
in your source code which are not nullified in your release build
because you have failed to define the preprocessor macro `NDEBUG`.
Unless `assert()` is nullified, it invokes `__FILE__` - and `assert()`
will not be nullified if you do not define `NDEBUG`.

If indeed all of the non-strippable paths in your release executable
are due to non-nullified `assert()`s then you can get rid of them
by adding `-DNDEBUG` to the preprocessor flags of your release build.

Comment: There were `__FILE__` references. I have removed those. `objdump --syms` results in "no symbols" and I am using `-DNDEBUG` so I'm not compiling for debug. `readelf` only shows one thing I don't want in there, and it's the `Library rpath`. Still `strings` shows "/home/kmort/longPathHere/filename1.cpp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/filename2.dir/__/__/__/__/__/longPathHere/filename1.cpp.o
/home/kmort/longPathHere/filename2.cpp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/filename2.dir/__/__/__/__/__/longPathHere/filename2.cpp.o", etc,  which makes me think it's coming from the linker. Any thoughts?